# Semantic UI checkall not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox, semantic-ui

I'm using SemanticUI and the checkall feature is not working. Here is my code

```
jQuery('.ui.checkbox.selectAll').checkbox( {
    onChange: function(){
        formObj = this[0].form;
        checkall(formObj.SelectAllBox,formObj.UserID);
     }
});
```

And my **checkall** function is

```
function checkall(c,t){
    for(i=0; i<t.length; i++) t[i].checked=c.checked;
}
```

HTML code

```
<form name="form1" action="action.cfm" method="post">
    <div class="ui checkbox selectAll">
        <input type="checkbox" name="SelectAllBox" value="select_all" >
    </div>
    <div class="ui checkbox">
        <input type="checkbox" name="UserID" value="#UserID#">
    </div>
</form>
```

I've tried with many guidance and documentation but no luck. Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this :

```
$('input[name="SelectAllBox"]').change(function(){
    if($('input[name="SelectAllBox"]').attr('checked')=='checked'){
        $('input[name="UserID"]').attr('checked',true);
    }else{
        $('input[name="UserID"]').attr('checked',false);
    }
});
```

Comment: Strange! I Tried with ordinary jQuery and its not working. Find some code like checkbox('enable'). But its working fine!